# A dedicated server runs mysql ONLY,but can only use 20% cpu,why?

Tags: mysql

as you may see ,for this server the CPU can be use for up to 20%.it would not raise even mysql start to stuck. this server runs mysql ONLY because such php nginx etc is in other server.i assume there is some error in the my.conf,please help.

screenshot after type "top" in centos is as flow

[image]

about hardware ,it is dual Xeon E5-2620 V2. 32G RAM.

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep name | cut -f2 -d: | uniq -c
24  Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v2 @ 2.10GHz
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "physical"| sort |uniq -c
24 address sizes    : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
12 physical id  : 0
12 physical id  : 1
```

here is my.conf(mysql 5.6.14)

```
[mysqld]
port        = 3306
;socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
log-error=/var/log/mysql-error.log
slow_query_log=1
;log_queries_not_using_indexes=1
;log-slow-queries=/var/log/mysql-slow.log
;log_slow_queries=1
;slow_query_log_file=/var/log/mysql-slow.log
;long_query_time=10
log-output=FILE
slow_query_log_file=/var/log/mysql-slow.log
;long-query-time=10
skip-external-locking
table_open_cache = 8192
max_allowed_packet = 1024M
table_definition_cache = 1024
max_connections = 1000
max_connect_errors = 10
max_heap_table_size =64M
sort_buffer_size = 8M
join_buffer_size = 1M
thread_cache_size = 64
thread_concurrency = 24
query_cache_size = 256M
query_cache_limit = 4M
tmp_table_size = 1024M
key_buffer_size = 5G
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 16M
bulk_insert_buffer_size= 64M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 128M
myisam_max_sort_file_size = 256M
myisam_repair_threads = 1
myisam_recover
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 1024M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 256M
innodb_log_file_size = 1024M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 10G
[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: 798.2% does not seem very close to 20%...

Comment: the 798.2% will be up to 800%. when i ask it is not clear sorry about that......meanwhile in the screenshot 19.3% will be up to 20%. also i am confuse about the 800% number ,it is a 12*2 cpu...

Comment: It's using 8 CPUs (100% = 1 CPU). As with Oliver, I don't see where you get 20% from.

Comment: even so ,can i use more then 8 cpus? there is 24 core.PS: shouldn't 19.3% can be higher? or i misunderstand about that number?thanks

Comment: extraly. that is what i concern.